# Vue component's props turns into undefined

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

Hi I have a weird problem

i have a Vue component that take some props. Before in the code the component was only registered locally and it worked fine, but due to changes in the system, I needed to register it globally also, but then this weird issue came up.

all the props in the component, no matter what you pass to it is undefined

in the parent I use the component like so:

```
<questionnaire
    v-if="questionnaire !== null && questions !== null && informationAssets !==  null"
    :current_status="savestatus"
    :questionnaire="questionnaire" 
    :informationAssets="informationAssets"
    :questions="questions"
    v-on:questionChange="updateQuestion(arguments[0], arguments[1])">
 </questionnaire>
```

then inside the questionnaire component i console.log the parents data and the prop in the created hook:

```
created() {
        console.log(this.questionnaire, this.questions, this.informationAssets)
        console.log(this.$parent.questionnaire, this.$parent.questions, this.$parent.informationAssets)
}
```

so here's the funny part. when we look at the console.log i get

```
undefined undefined undefined
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
{…} 
(36) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer] 
{__ob__: Observer}
```

so when the questionnaire component loads, the data is present in the parent (as expected) but the props are still undefined.

I really don't get this. Is there a problem with both locally register a component and globally register it, but under a different name.

when the component tries to load it won't render and gives this error

```
vue.js:583 [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"
warn @ vue.js:583
logError @ vue.js:1578
globalHandleError @ vue.js:1573
handleError @ vue.js:1562
(anonymous) @ vue.js:1680
flushCallbacks @ vue.js:1599
Promise.then (async)
microTimerFunc @ vue.js:1645
nextTick @ vue.js:1691
queueWatcher @ vue.js:2791
update @ vue.js:2917
notify @ vue.js:681
reactiveSetter @ vue.js:964
proxySetter @ vue.js:3005
(anonymous) @ information-assets-processor.vue?cf9d:347
Promise.then (async)
getData @ information-assets-processor.vue?cf9d:346
created @ information-assets-processor.vue?cf9d:574
callHook @ vue.js:2650
Vue._init @ vue.js:4123
VueComponent @ vue.js:4291
createComponentInstanceForVnode @ vue.js:3842
init @ vue.js:3690
createComponent @ vue.js:5025
createElm @ vue.js:4979
patch @ vue.js:5549
Vue._update @ vue.js:2416
updateComponent @ vue.js:2521
get @ vue.js:2850
run @ vue.js:2927
flushSchedulerQueue @ vue.js:2711
(anonymous) @ vue.js:1678
flushCallbacks @ vue.js:1599
Promise.then (async)
microTimerFunc @ vue.js:1645
nextTick @ vue.js:1691
queueWatcher @ vue.js:2791
update @ vue.js:2917
notify @ vue.js:681
reactiveSetter @ vue.js:964
(anonymous) @ vue-router.esm.js:2353
(anonymous) @ vue-router.esm.js:2352
updateRoute @ vue-router.esm.js:1884
(anonymous) @ vue-router.esm.js:1759
(anonymous) @ vue-router.esm.js:1869
step @ vue-router.esm.js:1604
step @ vue-router.esm.js:1611
runQueue @ vue-router.esm.js:1615
(anonymous) @ vue-router.esm.js:1864
step @ vue-router.esm.js:1604
(anonymous) @ vue-router.esm.js:1608
(anonymous) @ vue-router.esm.js:1847
(anonymous) @ vue-router.esm.js:1679
iterator @ vue-router.esm.js:1832
step @ vue-router.esm.js:1607
step @ vue-router.esm.js:1611
runQueue @ vue-router.esm.js:1615
confirmTransition @ vue-router.esm.js:1855
transitionTo @ vue-router.esm.js:1758
addRoutes @ vue-router.esm.js:2429
addRoutes @ risma.vue?2a44:51
(anonymous) @ index.js:120
i @ jquery-2.2.4.min.js?v=6.5.5:2
fireWith @ jquery-2.2.4.min.js?v=6.5.5:2
ready @ jquery-2.2.4.min.js?v=6.5.5:2
J @ jquery-2.2.4.min.js?v=6.5.5:2

vue.js:1582 TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
at o.render (questionnaire.vue?9925:6)
at o.Re.n._render (vue.min.js:6)
at o.<anonymous> (vue.min.js:6)
at Vi.get (vue.min.js:7)
at new Vi (vue.min.js:7)
at o.e._mount (vue.min.js:6)
at o.Be.$mount (vue.min.js:8)
at o.Be.$mount (vue.min.js:8)
at init (vue.js:3691)
at createComponent (vue.js:5025)
logError @ vue.js:1582
globalHandleError @ vue.js:1573
handleError @ vue.js:1562
(anonymous) @ vue.js:1680
flushCallbacks @ vue.js:1599
Promise.then (async)
microTimerFunc @ vue.js:1645
nextTick @ vue.js:1691
queueWatcher @ vue.js:2791
update @ vue.js:2917
notify @ vue.js:681
reactiveSetter @ vue.js:964
proxySetter @ vue.js:3005
(anonymous) @ information-assets-processor.vue?cf9d:347
Promise.then (async)
getData @ information-assets-processor.vue?cf9d:346
created @ information-assets-processor.vue?cf9d:574
callHook @ vue.js:2650
Vue._init @ vue.js:4123
VueComponent @ vue.js:4291
createComponentInstanceForVnode @ vue.js:3842
init @ vue.js:3690
createComponent @ vue.js:5025
createElm @ vue.js:4979
patch @ vue.js:5549
Vue._update @ vue.js:2416
updateComponent @ vue.js:2521
get @ vue.js:2850
run @ vue.js:2927
flushSchedulerQueue @ vue.js:2711
(anonymous) @ vue.js:1678
flushCallbacks @ vue.js:1599
Promise.then (async)
microTimerFunc @ vue.js:1645
nextTick @ vue.js:1691
queueWatcher @ vue.js:2791
update @ vue.js:2917
notify @ vue.js:681
reactiveSetter @ vue.js:964
(anonymous) @ vue-router.esm.js:2353
(anonymous) @ vue-router.esm.js:2352
....
```

I really need a sharp minded Vue expert, to tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Is your app using SSR by any chance?

Comment: SSR? I don't think so?

Comment: ohh server side rendering? well in part of the app, yes

Comment: Might not be that but just for test purpose try to change 'created' by 'mounted' and check if its still undefined

Comment: they are still undefined if you console.log them from the mounted hook

Comment: but the component still shows on the page? with no error messages?

Comment: nope it doesn't render. i posted the error at it throws